# Calling a java method which expects a class as argument in clojure

Tags: java, clojure, interop, metadata-extractor

I'm trying to call a java method (of https://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor) in clojure which expects a class as parameter.

**Java:**

```
metadata.getDirectory(GpsDirectory.class)
```

**My Clojure-Code:**

```
(.getDirectory metadata GpsDirectory)
```

ends up in the following exception:

```
IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: com.drew.metadata.exif.GpsDirectory  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:505)
```

I have imported the java lib via namespace

```
(ns MyProject.exif
(:import [java.io File BufferedInputStream FileInputStream]
       [com.drew.imaging ImageMetadataReader]
       [com.drew.metadata.exif GpsDirectory]
       [com.drew.metadata Directory]))
```

Does anybody have any idea how to call those methods (expecting a class) in clojure?

Comment: Have you checked the examples [here](http://clojure.org/java_interop)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
(.getDirectory metadata (class (GpsDirectory.)))
```

Comment: you are right! But (.getDirectory metadata GpsDirectory) works too. The error was at another point in the code. I tried to pass an object of GpsDirectory to map (http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.3.0/clojure.core/map) so the compiler did not know how to create a sequence of com.drew.metadata.exif.GpsDirectory. -.- thanks for your quick response!

Comment: Yes, me too was a bit surprised, so I answered calling the constructor (maybe some other code was overriding the classname symbol). Anyway in your case I'd prefer calling the plain "(.getDirectory metadata GpsDirectory)", so that you can avoid an aimless instance.